# Java plugin classpath gradle

Tags: java, gradle

In the [gradle documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N10581) (sec. 8.3) defined the java plugin classpath.

> In Gradle dependencies are grouped into configurations. A
>   configuration is simply a named set of dependencies. We will refer to
>   them as dependency configurations. You can use them to declare the
>   external dependencies of your project. As we will see later, they are
>   also used to declare the publications of your project.

Is it the same as the Java classpath we define as `export CLASSPATH = ...`?

Comment: Nope. It is more than that. Think of it as a bucket which handles dependencies. From Java plugin, you get configurations like compile, runtime, testCompile etc which handles dependencies in respective manner. You can have your own configuration and use that configuration for xyz dependency. Now what you do with that configuration dictates how you handle the dependencies under that configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adding comment as answer with an example*

It is more than that. Think of it as a bucket which handles dependencies. From Java plugin, we get configurations like compile, runtime, testCompile etc which handles dependencies in respective manner. You can have your own configuration and use that configuration for any dependency. Now what you do with that configuration dictates how you handle the dependencies under that configuration.

For example, here is a sample configuration setup which extracts a zip archive and copies its content to a directory.

```
configurations {
    extractZips // custom configuration
}

dependencies {
    extractZips 'com.mycompany:my-dependency:0.1@zip'
}

// Task configured to copy contents from zip archive
task extractZip(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree( configurations.extractZips.singleFile )
    into "$projectDir/zips" // for example
}
```